# bash script youtube filtering

Tags: android, linux, bash, termux

The goal is to be able to send video urls to two metube dockers. One just for YouTube and one for everything else but YouTube.

This script is going to go in my phone for use with termux url opener which opens as a argument `$url`

```
#!/bin/bash
# $url will contain a url to a video for processing on youtube-dl

# this will only take youtube urls and not others
if [[ $url =~ ['^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com)\/.+$'] ]] || [[ $url =~ ['^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtu\.be)\/.+$'] ]]
then 
    #curl -X POST https://metube.domain.com/add -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"url\":\"$1\",\"quality\":\"1440p\"}" 
    echo "Sent To Metube"
fi

# this will take any url other then youtube
if [[ "$url" =~ ['^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.a-zA-Z0-9\.com)\/.+$'] ]]
then
    #curl -X POST https://metube2.domain.com/add -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"url\":\"$1\",\"quality\":\"1440p\"}"
    echo "Sent To Metube2"
fi
```

Comment: What is your question? BTW, when you use `[something]` in a regular expression, that'll match any single character from what's inside it (i.e. in this example, it'd match "s" or "o" or "m" or "e" or ...).

Comment: i need the script to send only youtube.com or youtu.be to metube.
and anything else to metube2. (facebook.com goes to metube2) 
right now i cant get it working right.
ive have it send all to metube or after playing around with it all to metube2. i cant get the right split.